# multiple imputation models containing categorical variables

Tags: multiple-imputation, many-categories

I have been using multiple imputation to estimate missing values in a single continuous exposure variable. One of the variables used in my imputation model is a categorical variable (occupation), with many categories (>50).

Say a subject with missing exposure data has an occupation equal to X. It turns out that only three subjects total have that same occupation X and all three have missing exposure data. When trying to predict their exposures, how does the model handle the occupation variable in such a case?

Must there exist a subject who holds occupation X and has a known exposure for the model to work correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you model the occupation's 'effect' on the exposure as a fixed effect (which is the default in most imputation implementations), i.e. estimating a separate coefficient for each occupation, then the answer to your question is yes. You must have some individuals with exposure observed and that level of occupation, in order to estimate the conditional mean of the exposure for that exposure level. Without this, the imputation model has no basis on which to impute the missing exposure values for those with that occupation.

A possible workaround may be, for the purposes of imputation, to collapse that occupation category together with another one (which has some observed exposure values). Ideally you would want to collapse it into another occupation for which you (based on your external knowledge/belief) has a similar exposure distribution.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I figured. Great idea for a work around!